# $f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{4}c_{j}e^{r_{j}x} \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{4}d_{j}e^{s_{j}x}$. How to determine $c_{j},d_{j}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, exponential-function

Let $\alpha_{i},\beta_{i} \in \mathbb{C}$, $\forall i= 1,2$ and $0 < a < b < \infty$.
\begin{align}
&f^{\prime \prime} + \alpha_{1} f = \alpha_{2} g^{\prime} \quad \text{in} \quad [a,b] \\
&g^{\prime \prime} - \beta_{1} g = \beta_{2}f^{\prime} \quad \text{in} \quad [a,b].
\end{align}
with $f(b) = g(a)=g(b)=0$.

Well, doing the appropriate manipulations we arrive at a problem of analyzing the roots of a biquadratic equation and transforming it into a problem of determining the roots of a quadratic equation - I have no doubt about this part - so I'll post the result straight away. I get the following solutions:
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{4}c_{j}e^{r_{j}x} \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{4}d_{j}e^{s_{j}x}
\end{align}
with $r_{1},,s_{j} \in \mathbb{C}$. I'm having difficulty finishing these constants $c_{j}$ and $d_{j}$. I've tried substituting these equations into the system and using boundary conditions, but I'm not getting anything relevant. How to proceed intelligently?

Comment: The boundary conditions and the differential equation at $6$ interior points should yield a system of $8$ linear equations for $8$ unknowns. The solution may not be pretty, but that is one way.